# Tinymce y ASP.NET(c#) Webmatrix

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

Buenas, tengo una situación, introdusco datos a mi DB sql mediante un textarea con tinymce, en la base de datos se guarda algo como esto:

```
<div class="f kv _SWb" style="color: #808080; height: 17px; line-height: 16px; font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: small; white-space: nowrap;"><cite class="_Rm" style="color: #006621; font-style: normal; font-size:
```

Mi problema es que al llamar ese texto desde la base de datos y mostrarlo via **cshtml** sale igual sin formato, y la idea del **tinymce** es que tenga formato.

No sé que estoy haciendo mal, en la DB lo guardo en **NVARCHAR**, ya lo he puesto en las etiquetas de `<p> <textbox>`....... en fin en todas las etiquetas y sigue mostrandose sin formato, no sé que hacer... ayuda.

Comment: hola Atejada, bienvenid@ a SOes, ayudaría mucho si agregas el código del lado del servidor. Por cierto, date una vuelta por http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para que veas cómo funciona el sitio :D Saludos!

Comment: pero si es un cshtml entonces usas asp.net mvc ? porque como tag has puesto asp.net y no asp.net mvc

Comment: quizás te sea de utilidad: http://www.slideshare.net/fredyfx/tutorial-ms-web-matrixv4 saludos :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias intentar usando

```
@Html.Raw(Model.PropContenidoHtml)
```

de esta forma se renderizara el html en el browser

[HtmlHelper.Raw Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx)